# Вход в админпанель

Tags: mysqli, php

Здравствуйте, подскажите как сделать админку более лучше для своего сайта ну и безопаснее кто что знает)

ну вот я видел к примеру такое что заходим на один файл admin.php если не вошел ещё в админку то входишь и уберается форма входа средствами php после обновления страницы и перед нами админка на этом же файле admin.php подскажите как такое релизовать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if ( !$loggedin ) {
 echo "Вы не залогинены!";
} elseif ( $loggedin ) {
 echo "Вы залогинены!";
} else {
 echo "Эм, индусский true|false|else :)";
}
```